# Guardar imagen temporalmente cargada con "AsyncFileUpload"

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente para mostrar una imagen al momento de cargarla con el AsyncFileUpload, el problema que tengo es que me guarda la imagen en la ruta que le puse, pero quisiera que esa ruta sea temporal porque para guardarlo quiero ocupar el boton, no halle una manera de mostrar las imágenes sin que me guarde el archivo y es que eso me ocupa memoria y no lo puedo borrar ademas en mi carpeta tengo dos veces el mismo archivo una ves que presione el boton

Codigo asp.net

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
<!-- imagen 1-->
<div class="thumbnail">
    <asp:Image  class="imgpub" src="../img/ico_img.png" ID="displayImage" runat="server"  />
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload  PersistFile="true" class="pruebaos" ID="AsyncFileUpload2" runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var imageName = args.get_fileName();
            $get("displayImage").src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + imageName;
        }
</script>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
<!-- imagen 2-->
<div class="thumbnail">
    <asp:Image  class="imgpub" src="../img/ico_img.png" ID="Image1" runat="server"  />
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload PersistFile="true" class="pruebaos" ID="AsyncFileUpload3" runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete2" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete2(sender, args) {
            var imageName = args.get_fileName();
            $get("Image1").src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath2) %>" + imageName;
        }
</script>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<asp:Button ID="btn_gua_rda" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" class="btn-full btn-lg btn-blue" Text="Publicar" onclick="btn_gua_rda_Click" ></asp:Button>
</div>
</div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updboton"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_gua_rda" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Este es el codigo de lado del servidor para mostrar la imagen:

```
        protected string UploadFolderPath = "~/images/alquilerimagenes/";

        protected void FileUploadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
            AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath) + filename);
        }
        protected string UploadFolderPath2 = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

        protected void FileUploadComplete2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload2.FileName);
            AsyncFileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(this.UploadFolderPath2) + filename2);
        }
```

y para el evento click del boton, el que guarda a la base de datos tengo el siguiente codigo (quisiera que solo cuando le de click guarde la imagen) no cuando la visualize en mi pagina

```
 protected void btn_gua_rda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Insertar Imagenes
                if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    string SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/images/alquilerimagenes/") + va_cod_pub;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(SavePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath);
                    }
                    string extencion = Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(SavePath + "\\" + tb_tit_pub.Text.ToString().Trim() + "01" + extencion);
                    //guarda en la base de datos
                    o_ima001._02(tb_tit_pub.Text.ToString().Trim() + "01", extencion, va_cod_pub.ToString());
                }
                if (AsyncFileUpload2.HasFile)
                {
                    string SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/images/alquilerimagenes/") + va_cod_pub;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(SavePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath);
                    }
                    string extencion = Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
                    AsyncFileUpload2.SaveAs(SavePath + "\\" + tb_tit_pub.Text.ToString().Trim() + "02" + extencion);
                    //guarda en la base de datos
                    o_ima001._02(tb_tit_pub.Text.ToString().Trim() + "02", extencion, va_cod_pub.ToString());
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, te recomiendo que para eso utilices css o en su defecto un plugin de jquery, el cual en lugar de crear una imagen con una "ruta temporal" solo te creara una previsualizacion, para que luego, por medio del boton asignado, puedas subirla con la ruta que definas.

Te dejo el link de un plugin el cual me parece de los mejores por los simple que es para utilizarlo pero le da un acabado perfecto a la forma en que subes tus archivos o imagenes, yo lo utilizo bastante y no me a fallado hasta la fecha: [Dropify](http://jeremyfagis.github.io/dropify/)

**Editado:**

Te dejo el link donde reproduje un ejemplo de como utilizar el plugin: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvelasquezdev/xuc217hr/9/)

Solo tienes que asignarlo a tu input file como hice yo en el ejemplo:

Con eso te evitaras el proceso que realizas. Luego lo unico que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente, cuando utilizas dropify, seleccionas la foto y esta lo que hace es mostrarte una previsualizacion de la img que necesitas subir, no la guarda ni nada. Entonces, al tener la previsualizacion, te ahorras el paso de subir una imagen para ver como queda. Luego lo unico que tienes que hacer es lo mismo pero omitiendo la subida de la imagen 2. Y por ultimo, asignas la imagen almacenada a cualquier control asp:img y tu codigo deberia funcionar correctamente.

Si estas teniendo problemas con la carga o porque te esta devolviendo null o false entonces no es problema de sincronizacion, lo que puede pasar es que tu segunda imagen aun no se guarda y el proceso continua normalmente. Para validad esto podrias implementar un While a la hora de guardar, compruebas que la imagen ya existe en la ubicacion, mientras no exista, que el codigo se quede "estancado" y cuando exista, lo dejas pasar y no tendrias que tener problemas de return false o null.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias gracias por responder en cuanto vi tu respuesta realize unas pruebas adaptando el el ejemplo a mi codigo, no lo puedo subir por Respuesta pero te lo dejo mas abajo porfavor poderia seguir ayudandome con eso..  Nesecito utilizar el AsyncFileUpload  de AJAX para poder evitar el Return False de Input o FileUpload

Comment: Ahorita actualizo mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

@francisco intente aplicar Drpify a mi codigo y quedo de la siguiente manera Pero aun sigue sin funcionoar


    
        Dropify — Override your input files with style.

```
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Now</h2>
                <label for="input-file-now">Your so fresh input file — Default version</label>

                <input type="file" id="input-file-now" class="dropify" />

                 <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload PersistFile="true" type="file" id="fil_up1" class="dropify" runat="server" />

                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Button ID="btn_gua_rda" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" class="btn-full btn-lg btn-blue" Text="Publicar" OnClick="btn_gua_rda_Click1" ></asp:Button>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updboton"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_gua_rda" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropify.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Basic
            $('.dropify').dropify();

            // Translated
            $('.dropify-fr').dropify({
                messages: {
                    default: 'Glissez-déposez un fichier ici ou cliquez',
                    replace: 'Glissez-déposez un fichier ou cliquez pour remplacer',
                    remove:  'Supprimer',
                    error:   'Désolé, le fichier trop volumineux'
                }
            });

            // Used events
            var drEvent = $('#input-file-events').dropify();

            drEvent.on('dropify.beforeClear', function(event, element){
                return confirm("Do you really want to delete \"" + element.file.name + "\" ?");
            });

            drEvent.on('dropify.afterClear', function(event, element){
                alert('File deleted');
            });

            drEvent.on('dropify.errors', function(event, element){
                console.log('Has Errors');
            });

            var drDestroy = $('#input-file-to-destroy').dropify();
            drDestroy = drDestroy.data('dropify')
            $('#toggleDropify').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (drDestroy.isDropified()) {
                    drDestroy.destroy();
                } else {
                    drDestroy.init();
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
        </form>
</body>
```